# Hikari can't recover from connection error

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

I have a Spring boot application that handles 1K QPS. One day Aurora Replica MySQL instance was restarted by AWS (it was a host replacement), so all our replica connection was lost but database came back online after some time but application could not recover from the connection error.  We kept getting the same error `No operations allowed after connection closed` until we restarted the app.

### Application

Spring Boot: 2.3.12

Hikari Version: 3.4.5

### Hikari Configuration:

- connectionTimeout = 3 seconds
- idleTimeout = 10 minutes
- maxLifeTime = 30 minutes
- minimumIde = 15
- maximumPoolSize = 150
- leakDetectionThreshold=3000

We observed a large number of errors like No operations allowed after the connection closed. post database restart, this error continues to occur until we restarted the application.

Our Aurora RDS Replica node was restarted due to some issue (unknown to us), post replica restart all existing and new connections started throwing errors and the application kept getting the same error. Even after digging through the Hikari code, I'm not able to find why Hikari kept getting the same error even though the database had recovered after some time.

For timeline, the database recovered at 7:48 PM but the application kept getting the same error till 8:02 PM (until restart).

All stack traces are the same that look like

```
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor330.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_342]at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.checkClosed(NativeSession.java:761) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:568) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setNetworkTimeout(ConnectionImpl.java:2481) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
... 143 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:73) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setNetworkTimeout(ConnectionImpl.java:2485) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setNetworkTimeout(PoolBase.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:173) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
```

Also, we observed another warning message `Failed to validate connection` that lasted only for a few seconds, from the code it seems this error occurs when Hikari is able to catch the exception in the try-catch block in the isConnectionAlive method.

[image]

In this case, as a database would have closed the connection so the driver is saying the connection has been closed but Hikari keeps trying to use the same connection again and again for a very long time. Error log for one of the containers, it kept getting the same error for 20 minutes until termination.

[image]

What could be the reason behind Hikari's repeated attempts to utilize the old/stale connection?

One possible explanation for Hikari's persistence in using the stale connection could be that they were not able to detect that the connection had been closed by the server, leading to repeated failed attempts to utilize them.

I've raised this [issue](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/2056) on their GitHub page as well.